# Is there any way to install ubuntu on a chinese android device?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a chinese mobile phone named JiaYu G4, and I would like to know if there is any possible way to install Ubuntu os on it.. I am beginner with programming, and if I need to port a rom can anyone help me with the source and a good guide to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu for Android is not available yet.
If you want to try to do a port for your device of Ubuntu Touch, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting